# Targeting specific text between tags using regex

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I'm trying to get select just the string "Target" case-sensitive without grabbing any extra space before or after in HTML code, and not getting tags or tag attributes.
I have this regex:

```
/(?![^<>]*>) *(Target) *([^ \d])/g
```

This does grab multiple occurences of :Target, but it also grabs extra spaces before and after, the first character that follows it or extra whitespace after it.
In`<div id="Target">text Target othertext</div>` it grabs `Target o`
How do I perfect this?

Comment: You don't want to be parsing HTML with regular expressions.  Use a proper HTML parser.  There is certain to be one for your language of choice.  Which language are you writing in?

Comment: I'm doing it in Javascript currently, which I'm relatively new to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you're using to handle the RegEx, it could be because you're using multiple capture groups. I'd change the other capture groups to non-capturing by prefixing them with `?:`:

```
/(?:?![^<>]*>) *(Target) *(?:[^ \d])/g
```

**EDIT:**

With the additional information from the comments, shouldn't this work?

```
var str="<div id=\"Target\">text Target othertext</div>";
str = str.replace(/Target/g,"New!");
```

**EDIT #2:**

Here's a pass that starts with your original regex and uses some information from [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447915/javascript-string-regex-backreferences):

```
var str="<div id=\"Target\">text Target othertext</div><Target test=\"nothing\">Target this is Targeted.</Target>";
alert(str.replace(/(?![^<>]*>)( *)Target( *[^ \d])/g,function(str,group1,group2){return group1 + "NEW!" + group2;}));
```

I've tested it myself and it seems to do what you need...or at least get you further along.

Comment: I was trying to apply something like that, but this one doesn't seem to want to capture anything.

Comment: What are you using to evaluate the regex? A library? Text editor?

Comment: I'm trying to find and replace html with Javascript. Sorry just realized I didn't include that in the question.

Comment: Please see the edited answer based on this information and some of my own testing.

Comment: It does replace "Target" but it also gets and replaces the id, which I'm trying to avoid. Sorry again if this wasn't clear. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I see that now. Edited again and expanded the test case to ensure I'm catching everything.