# Regex replace Harvard style bibliography references \d{4}:\s\d+ with comma

Tags: regex

Harvard bibliography, if you do not use Mendeley on time can get tough.

```
[Sihler 1999: 122; Trask 2000: 164]. 
[Benveniste 1935: 170-171, Бенвенист 1955, Bomhard, Kerns 1994: 56-59].
```

The way I quote authors in my PhD is wrong. It should have had a `,` instead of `:`. Like

```
[Sihler 1999, 122; Trask 2000, 164].
```

With `\d{4}:\s\d+` http://regex101.com/r/mE0rT9/1 I can find them, but how to replace `,` instead of `:` in Word? Thanks.

Comment: Which language are you running?

Comment: VBA, a kind of JS in MS Office, Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use lookahead and lookbehind or backreferences, http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html.

I would probably do something like this: preg_replace("~(\d{4}):(\s\d+)~", "$1,$2", $str) in php for instance as an example of the latter solution.

Here's a post which talks about backreferences in javascript: [JavaScript - string regex backreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447915/javascript-string-regex-backreferences)

Comment: Regex dialects tend to vary greatly. You'll have to find the equivalent constructs in your language.

Answer (score 0):

## Expression:

`(?<=\d{4})\:`

It uses a lookbehind to match but not return the year.

Comment: https://github.com/gasyoun/SanskritMacros/issues/2 documented what really worked for me in MS Word 2007, thanks.