# regular expression to insert * at proper places in an equation

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an expression such as **xsin(x)** it is valid only if * comes between x and sin(x) and make it as **x*sin(x)**

my idea is first search for x then insert * between x and another variable if there is a variable.

equation

1. `sin(x)cos(x) to sin(x)*cos(x)`
2. `pow((x),(2))sin(x)to pow((x),(2))*sin(x)`
3. `sin(x)cos(x)tan(x) to sin(x)*cos(x)*tan(x)`

   etc

I am trying with this code..

```
function cal(str)
{

  //var string = "3*x+56";
  var regex = /([a-z]+)\(\(([a-z]+)\),\(([0-9]+)\)\)\(([a-z0-9\*\+]+)\)([\*\-%\/+]*)/;
  var replacement = "$1($2($4),($3))$5";
  while(str.match(regex))
    {
      str = str.replace(regex,replacement);
    }
  return str;
}
```

Comment: @ tushar using javascript

Comment: @tushar it not working .

Comment: Please give a list of some possible equations (before & after). I assume we are not just talking about `x*sin(x)`?

Comment: @tushar i need to get * between sin(x)cos(x) also

Comment: if we count the number of open braces '(' and if it is equal to number of close one ')'. Then replace that match with '(anything)*anything_else' only if next char is not an operator.

Comment: @Rohit but how do we handle it if is xsin(x).

Comment: x is a variable, it can be named as x, y, z or even sin.(too complex)..another option you might try is to add functions names(sin,cos,tan,pow etc) in a array and use it with regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one matches right parentheses followed by a letter (e.g. `)s` ), and inserts a `*` (e.g. `)*s` )

It also replaces `x` followed by a letter with `x*` and that letter

It should work for `x+sin(x)` and `xsin(x)`

```js
function addStars(str) {
    return str.replace(/(\))([A-Za-z])/g,function(str, gr1, gr2) { return gr1 + "*" + gr2 }).replace(/x([A-Za-wy-z])/g,function(str, gr1) { return "x*" + gr1 })
}

document.write(addStars("x+sin(x)tan(x)ln(x)+xsin(x)"))
```

Help from:
[JavaScript - string regex backreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447915/javascript-string-regex-backreferences)
[qwertymk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33162250/2033574)'s answer

Comment: you are partially correct . i am not getting it correct for xsin(x).

Comment: now it is perfec.you are amazing Josiah.Thanks for all others  for helping me

Answer (score 2):

```
> 'sin(x)cos(x)'.replace(/(?!^)\w{3}/g, '*$&')
< "sin(x)*cos(x)"
> 'pow((x),(2))sin(x)'.replace(/(?!^)\w{3}/g, '*$&')
< "pow((x),(2))*sin(x)"
> 'sin(x)cos(x)tan(x)'.replace(/(?!^)\w{3}/g, '*$&')
< "sin(x)*cos(x)*tan(x)"
```

This says: replace anything that doesn't start at the beginning and has three letters with a `*` and everything that matched

Comment: I not sure but seems it wrong for 'x+sin(x)'

Comment: yes Grundy you are correct .it is not working for x+sin(x)