# wrap dynamic insensitive string in span tag

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to wrap the dynamic insensitive string in span tag but $1 is coming in output. Please help me.

```js
     function focusSearchValue(data, value){
          var regEx = new RegExp((value), "ig");
       data = data.replace(regEx, "<span class=''>$1</span>"); 
                console.log(data);
       }
    
    focusSearchValue('SharePoint 2016, Team Collaboration Software Tools', 'sharepoint');
```

Answer (score 2):

The parentheses around `value` are not part of the pattern, and thus, your regex has no capturing group defined, that `$1` could refer to from the string replacement pattern. That is why `$1` is passed as a literal string as the replacement result.

You need to use `$&` to refer to the whole match (see [`String#replace` "Specifying a string as a parameter" section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)), and return the string:

```js
function focusSearchValue(data, value){
        var regEx = new RegExp(value.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), "ig");
        return data.replace(regEx, "<span class=''>$&</span>");
}

console.log(focusSearchValue('SharePoint 2016, Team Collaboration Software Tools', 'sharepoint'));
```

Since you pass a variable to the regex engine that should be parsed as a literal string, it is advisable to escape all special chars that may act as special regex metacharacters, hence the added escaping `.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. Here you stored the value in $&?

Comment: It is the regex engine that stores the whole match in Group 0, and the `$&` replacement backreference can be used to access that value.

Answer (score 0):

I find this syntax to be a little more intuitive, passing a function in as the second argument of `replace` (more info: [function as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447915/javascript-string-regex-backreferences), [regex escaping search terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex)):

```js
const reEscape = searchTerm => (
  searchTerm.replace(/[-{}()[/*+?.^$|\]\\]/g, "\\$&")
);

const addSpan = $1 => `<span>${$1}</span>`;

const focusSearchValue = (data, value) => {
  const regex = new RegExp(`${reEscape(value)}`, 'ig');
  return data.replace(regex, addSpan);
};

console.log(focusSearchValue('SharePoint 2016, Team Collaboration Software Tools', 'sharepoint'));
```