# .replace to add a new line after every 10 characters returns new atring with <br> hardcoded

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a line break after ever 5 characters in a column

```
value = "hellohowar"

return value.toString().replace(/(.{5})/g, "$1<br/>")
```

Expected:

```
hello
howar
```

actual

```
hello<br/>howar
```

Comment: If you want to add a line break "actual" result is right where your "expected" result is wrong. If you want to match actual with expected  you have to add a blank space, not a line break

Comment: If you need `"hello howar "` as output, just replace the line break with an empty space. If however you need "hello howar", without a trailing space at the end, it might be easier to split, then join the string: `"hellohowar".split( /(.{5})/ ).filter( Boolean ).join( ' ' );`

Comment: Sorry the editing messed it up. I need a line break and not a space

Comment: Then you have the answer right? If you need to insert the text into HTML, <br> is what you actually want. If you need it as plain text, just use \n instead of <br>.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
var value = "Hello Howar"
value = value.replace(/(.{5})/g, exampleReplace);

function exampleReplace(str, group1, group2) {
    return group1 + '\n'; // if u want add br tag, \n change to <br/>
}
```

Comment: What is group1 and group2 here?

Comment: The things you capture inside the regex by using the grouping `()` around them. So group1 is the 5 letters and group2 is undefined. Its equivalent to you using '$1' and '$2' as a string.

Comment: @Shilly Thanks for description.

Comment: @Kimaya I was looked at below topic. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2447977/8770033